# HTML Content Editable div: select text event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I have a div which is **contenteditable**

`<div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>`

The user can enter any content in there. Is there any way to get the event for when a user makes a selection within the div.

Something like:

```
$('.editable').onSelection(function(e, selection){alert(selection);}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selected text event trigger in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript) `:)` might help!

Comment: @Tats_innit thanks for the pointer. But http://stackoverflow.com/a/11786495/1008421 kind of solves the problem. But I would like to if there is some other better way to do this

Answer (score 13):

you could try something like this:

There is no 'selectend' event but we can work out when the user has finished selecting by watching the mouseup event

```
$(function () {
    $('.editable').on('selectstart', function () {
        $(document).one('mouseup', function() {
            alert(this.getSelection());
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: You might also want to add `keyup` in the same event handler as `mouseup` so that selecting text with the keyboard also works

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer by @Elliot and the comment by @Michael Bates, this seems to work flawlessly for both mouse and keyboard selection events (example is in TypeScript):

```
export function attachSelectionListener(element: HTMLElement) : void {
  if (!element.contentEditable) {
    return;
  }
  element.onselectstart = () => handleSelectionChange(element);
}

function handleSelectionChange(element: HTMLElement): void {
  document.onmouseup = () => retrieveSelection(element);
  document.onkeyup = () => retrieveSelection(element);
}

function retrieveSelection(element: HTMLElement) : void {
  const selection = document.getSelection();

  // Ignore empty selection
  if (!selection || !selection.toString()) {
    return;
  }
  alert(selection.toString());
}
```

When using this in your app, you probably want to check if you need to remove the listeners again at some point.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `addEventListener()`, because assigning `element.on{event} =` could remove another event. If a user is unaware that `attachSelectionListener()` sets `onselectstart`, `onmouseup`, and `onkeyup` they might even overwrite the listener themself by accident.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#ta').select(function() {
alert('Handler for .select() called.');
});
```

.select( handler(eventObject) ) Returns: jQuery
 Bind an event handler to the "select" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

.select( handler(eventObject) )
handler(eventObject)A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

.select( [eventData], handler(eventObject) )
eventDataA map of data that will be passed to the event handler.
handler(eventObject)A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

check [link](http://api.jquery.com/select/)

Comment: on.select does not fire for contenteditable. ref: "This event is limited to <input type="text"> fields and <textarea> boxes."