# Get Selected Text In ContentEditable DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

So I have a contenteditable div in my Rails app, and need to be able to display a little popup above text when it's highlighted. Currently I have code that works, and it displays the highlighted text in an alert. However, the function executes on mouseup, so when you click into the div to start typing or highlighting, it throws an empty alert.

Here's my code:

```js
function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        return document.getSelection();
    } else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if (selection.text) {
            return selection.text;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$("#content-create-partial").bind("mouseup", function () {
    var text = getSelected();
    if (text) {
        console.log(text);
    } else {
        console.log("Nothing selected?");
    }
});
```

How do I prevent jQuery from executing the function when the user clicks into the contentEditable div? I only want it to execute when actual text is highlighted.

Answer (score 6):

You can compare `window.getSelection().anchorOffset` and `window.getSelection().extentOffset` to see if they are equal. If they are, then it was just a normal click.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply check if the `Selection.toString()` method returns an empty string

```
if(window.getSelection().toString()){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.data.substring( window.getSelection().anchorOffset,window.getSelection().extentOffset )
```

Try Working Exmaple [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/surajmahajan007/r8m2eacw/).

Answer (score 3):

The following will return true if nothing is selected.

Inspired from @Tarun Dugar. But didn't work in all browsers. The following worked.

```
window.getSelection().focusOffset == window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is "selectstart" event which fires when user starts selection. There is no selection end event but you can listen for mouseup event after "selectstart" event fired to make sure selection has occurred.

Edit:

Check - [HTML Content Editable div: select text event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13286950/153207)

Answer (score -2):

Just check if the selection is empty: `if ($.trim( text) != '') ...`