# get selected texts inside content editable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do text editor and change the texts which is inside the content editable elements and also selected by the user.

my question is:
**How to get the selected texts inside the content editable elements?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="D:\JQueryPath\jquery-3.1.1.js">         </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#show").click(function(){
            //alert("selected texts");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="textEditor" style=" border:solid 1px #D31444" contenteditable="true" ></div>
<p></p>
<button id="show">show selected elements</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285877/html-content-editable-div-select-text-event/13286950#13286950 you can refer to this link

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to do. When you click the show btn what are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: if I click the button I want to alert the selected texts inside the (div)content editable element @DavidBrewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started, although you will need to consider expanding on this code to cater for situations where someone selects outside of your text area and when someone presses the button and nothing is selected.

Oh, and I have console logged the output rather than alerted it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    console.log(range.toString());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.getSelection()` method.

Comment: I am beginner and I don't know how to use window.getSelection() method. I searched but still I didn't find any correct answers which using this window.getSelection()  method

Comment: When the button is clicked, you can use this method inside the handler to retrieve currently selected text. and can show this in alert box.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="D:\JQueryPath\jquery-3.1.1.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show").click(function(){
        alert(window.getSelection().toString());
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="textEditor" style=" border:solid 1px #D31444"contenteditable="true" ></div>
<p></p>
<button id="show">show selected elements</button>
</body>
</html>
```