# (select) event doesn't work for div elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The user can type a text in a `div` that has the attribute `contenteditable="true"` and they can also select a text. I now would like to output the selected text.

This is what I have tried:

```html
<div (select)="getSelectedText()" contenteditable="true" #editor id="editor"></div>
```

```js
getSelectedText(): void {
  console.log(window.getSelection());
}
```

This is not working, probably because `(select)` is not available for `div`. This is what the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event) of it says:

> Element: select event
>
> The select event fires when some text has been selected.
>
> ...
>
> The event is not available for all elements in all languages. For example, in HTML, `select` events can be dispatched only on form [`<input type="text">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) and [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) elements.

Is there an alternative to this in Angular?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Content Editable div: select text event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285877/html-content-editable-div-select-text-event)

Comment: @CBroe no. My question is related to Angular only. Not jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: So what, that doesn't change the fact that you need to use a different event to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do but to listen either mouse, either to keyup event:

HTML

```
<div (keyup)="getSelectedText()" (mouseup)="getSelectedText()" contenteditable="true" #editor id="editor"></div>
```

TS

```
  getSelectedText(){
    console.log(document.getSelection()?.toString())
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5h6db?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Just what I wanted, thank you! However, `document.getSelection().toString()` gave me the error *TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.*. I have now changed it to `document.getSelection()?.toString()` and it works fine.

Comment: I edited the post to take in account the correction

Answer (score 0):

You should use a mouseup and mouseout event in your div and then call window.getSelection().toString() to get the selected text.

```
<div (mouseup)="getSelectedText()" (mouseout)="getSelectedText()"contenteditable="true" #editor id="editor"></div>

getSelectedText(): void {
   if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().toString();
    }
}
```

Ref : [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)