# Bold Selected Text in contentEditable div, using pure JavaScript without libraries such as jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable, selectedtext

We have an editable div and we want to change the style of the text, selected by the user, on clicking our button; just same as this editor's bold or italic button.

But when we click on the button our selected text get deselected.

So how to keep our selected text highlighted even if the focus from the editable is off and change the style.

My Code :

Editable Div:

```
var textbox= document.createElement("div");
textbox.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
```

Button :

```
var bold = document.createElement("div");
bold.innerHTML = "B";
```

Button Click:

```
bold.addEventListener("click", function(){
        getSelectedText();
},false);

    function getSelectedText()
    {
       var html = "";
       if (window.getSelection) {
         html = window.getSelection().toString();
       } 

       else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().text;
       }
       alert(html);
    }
```

Comment: Might need a listener to store the created range on blur.  That's how I'd approach it, at least.

Comment: Something seems to be afoot here. All the included code does is alerting the highlighted text, and that is working as intended.

Comment: Can't you just use an actual button for bold instead of div? The selection will remain then.

Comment: @Samurai an actual button wil do my job but i have to use the div only sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selection by listening to your `contentEditable`'s `onmouseup` and store it in a variable. After you clicked a div, you restore the selection to back what it was:

**Javascript:**

```
var range = "";

function getSelected() {
    var selection = window.getSelection()
    range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
}

function reselect() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();  
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/hkg88chg/3/)
used a button and a div for buttons so you can see the difference.

Comment: your jsfiddle bold button does nothing

Comment: In the jsfiddle provided the selected text is preserved when the button (or div) is clicked. The question was the selected text being deselected when the button is clicked (and the text losing focus).

Comment: thank you for the clarification, in that case it does work, this is another way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11787147/175071

Comment: This answer is incomplete by the way. You should fix the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the `mousedown` event instead of the `click` event or set the `<div>` button to be unselectable.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787147/96100) for details.